# Anchor link does not resolve to current page on subdomain URLs?

Tags: php, anchor

The php script below is included in my website template at the bottom of every page. It works perfectly on domains that are in the form http://somesite.com/page/

However, when the script is run on a site in the form somedirectory.somesite.com/page/, it resolves to the home page every time, rather than the current page (ie, its as if "/page/" where not there.)

```
return '<a href="#jump" class="backToTop">&uarr; Back to top</a>';
```

Update: I believe the problem is caused by my "Base HREF" in the head.

Comment: Please post more of the doc, and what do you mean by `somedirectory.somesite.doc/page/`? Give an example. What you're calling `somedirectory` is actually likely `someserver`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess that you have a `<base>` element in there somewhere, but it is hard to tell with just a fragment of the document.

Comment: you are spot on. I believe I have an issue with my base href that needs to be resolved.